# Email alert when OpenVPN disconnects

Tags: centos, openvpn, syslog

I am running OpenVPN client on my dedicated server to connect the server to a private network. Last week, the service (i.e. OpenVPN) disconnected itself and we did not realise until our customers started to ring us. I don't know the reason why it disconnected, Now I want to set up email alert as soon as the OpenVPN disconnects. How can I do that ? Can anyone help please.

By the way, the server is running CentOS 6.8

Thank you.

Comment: There are so many monitoring solutions to chose from ...

Comment: I know I can use `Monit`, `Pingdom`, `SIM (System Integrity Monitor)`, `Host-Tracker`, `Nagios` etc. But I am looking for a simple script locally!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to write a simple script to check if the service is running, if not, restart the service and send email. Here is the simple code

filename `checkprocess.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# timestamp
ts=`date +%m-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S`

if pgrep "openvpn" > /dev/null
then
    echo "$ts: OpenVPN running..." >> /etc/openvpn/myscript/processcheck.log
else
    echo "$ts: openvpn not running, restarting..." >> /etc/openvpn/myscript/processcheck.log 
    /etc/init.d/openvpn start > /dev/null >> /etc/openvpn/myscript/processcheck.log

    if pgrep "openvpn" > /dev/null
    then
        echo "$ts: openvpn started OK..." >> /etc/openvpn/myscript/processcheck.log
        echo "OpenVPN service went down, the service has been restarted." | mail -s "OpenVPN went down" email@domain.com
    else
        echo "$ts: openvpn not started..." >> /etc/openvpn/myscript/processcheck.log
        echo "OpenVPN service is down, the server is trying to restart the service." | mail -s "OpenVPN is down" email@domain.com
    fi
fi
```

put this file in `/etc/openvpn/myscript` and edit the cronjob

```
#crontab -e
```

Add the following line to run the script every 5 minutes

```
*/5 * * * * /etc/openvpn/myscript/checkprocess.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully set up one myself with these three steps

1. Follow [this](http://tecadmin.net/ways-to-send-email-from-linux-command-line/#) or find your own guide to configure the script for email notification
2. Open `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` and append the following lines

   ```
   script-security 2
   client-disconnect /path/to/script
   ```
3. Finally `chmod 755 /path/to/script`

---

Edit: Sorry, I misread your question. Add the two lines below to `client.conf`. This method is preferable over cronjob as it is almost instantaneous and doesn't flood you with mail

```
    script-security 2
    down /path/to/script
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but I am not running the OpenVPN server, I am only running client, please see my answer